# Comparing two cell strings to print out good or bad

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

Below is my VBA code that I have been racking my head around. I have 4 different values to compare against to get the result I want and multiple things to compare. If anyone could help me out with this, it would be great.

```
Public Sub cts_04_cmac_2_check()
    'CTS04CSPRWY CMAC 2 Check
    If (Sheet1.Range("A62") = "2.3.4/42/24/B1") And (Sheet1.Range("A63") = "2.3.4/42/1/B1") Then
            Sheet1.Range("C3").Value2 = "Good"
        Else
            Sheet1.Range("C3").Value2 = "Invalid"
    End If
    'End of CTS04CSPRWY CMAC 2 Check
End Sub
```

In reality I would love to have or statements included:

```
Public Sub cts_04_cmac_2_check()
    'CTS04CSPRWY CMAC 2 Check
    If (Sheet1.Range("A62") = "2.3.4/42/24/B1" Or Sheet1.Range("A62") = "2.3.4/42/24/B2) And (Sheet1.Range("A63") = "2.3.4/42/1/B1" Or Sheet1.Range("A63") = "2.3.4/42/1/B2") Then
            Sheet1.Range("C3").Value2 = "Good"
        Else
            Sheet1.Range("C3").Value2 = "Invalid"
    End If
    'End of CTS04CSPRWY CMAC 2 Check
End Sub
```

This compares 2 values to an arrays index table that changes based on a selection.

One more question is: can I continue to add additional If statements after an end if? I have about 256 checks to run through with the similar code above.

It compares these 2 Formulas:

=INDEX('Collective Node Data'!A2:AQ1048576, MATCH(I3,'Collective Node Data'!A2:A230, 0),15)
=INDEX('Collective Node Data'!A2:AQ1048576, MATCH(I3,'Collective Node Data'!A2:A230, 0),26)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNtlW.png)

Based off of this value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbUk9.png)

to get a "Good" or "Bad" in the CMTS Check Cells C3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PlqW.png)

Comment: You can use for loop to `256` checks

Comment: What are the 4 values and what does *multiple things to compare* mean?

Comment: So each check will be between each "CMAC" I have 3x56 "CMAC" Values and each value will hold 2 string values which is why I would like to have 2 checks. It's comparing "Is this OR this inside of this cell?" AND "is this OR this inside of THIS cell" if that's true, move to placing "Good" into C3. But I need it to continue to do this for many more values. It's checking the location for me to tell me if it's good or not.

Comment: A screenshot might help. I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does basically the same as your own, just condensed as you requested:

```vb
If (
     (  Sheet1.Range("A62") = "2.3.4/42/24/B1" And Sheet1.Range("A63") = "2.3.4/42/1/B1") Or _
     (  Sheet1.Range("A62") = "2.3.4/42/24/A1" And Sheet1.Range("A63") = "2.3.4/42/1/A1") Or _
     (  Sheet1.Range("A62") = "2.3.4/42/24/C1" And Sheet1.Range("A63") = "2.3.4/42/1/C1") _
   ) Then
        Sheet1.Range("C2").Value2 = "Good"
    Else
        Sheet1.Range("C2").Value2 = "Invalid"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the fix for this, thanks for tracking it and responding quickly!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$I$3")) Is Nothing Then
    Call ctscheck
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ctscheck()
'CTS04CSPRWY CMAC 2 Check
    If (Sheet1.Range("A62") = "2.3.4/42/24/B1") And (Sheet1.Range("A63") = "2.3.4/42/1/B1") Then
            Sheet1.Range("C2").Value2 = "Good"
        ElseIf (Sheet1.Range("A62") = "2.3.4/42/24/A1") And (Sheet1.Range("A63") = "2.3.4/42/1/A1") Then
            Sheet1.Range("C2").Value2 = "Good"
        ElseIf (Sheet1.Range("A62") = "2.3.4/42/24/C1") And (Sheet1.Range("A63") = "2.3.4/42/1/C1") Then
            Sheet1.Range("C2").Value2 = "Good"
        Else
            Sheet1.Range("C2").Value2 = "Invalid"
    End If
'End of CTS04CSPRWY CMAC 2 Check
End Sub
```

Just need to get the OR statements to work with this and it's golden. If anyone has suggestions on condensing this, let me know.